# FileA.Swift <--> FileB.Swift Scope: Accessing public entities

Tags: swift, scope

Is there a way to access typealias, functions, classes and structs defined in one .swift file from another .swift file?

I attempted to access a public func() and public class() defined in one .swift file from a different .swift file but failed:

Environment.swift:
[image]

MainViewController.swift:

[image]

Comment: You should able to acess these without public try cleaning project and build again.Clear derived data.Looks like indexing issue

Comment: Also make sure they're both included in your selected target.

Comment: This was a new project; however I did a code cleanse & reset simulator... and rebuilt the app.  Same problem.

Both .swift files are within the same target.

Perhaps I should file a bug report.

Comment: Note: I repeated this on my MacBook Pro "Guest Account".  
This time it works.  
So there's something wrong with my own account.  This type of thing had happened before.  I ended up re-creating my account.  A Royal Pain.

Comment: Ok... I created a brand new project and repeated it with my current account.  I got access to the new class() on a different .swift so I think I'm in the clear...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my Xcode project got corrupt.
I created a new project and repeated the pattern.
...occasionally, I find that a Xcode/Swift project appear to work like a 'loose light bulb' that needs to be tweaked/cleansed... or replaced to have a working solution.
This time it works.